# Firefox - enable mixed content (http inside https)

Tags: firefox

`http://` objects (like google maps) are not displayed on `https://` pages. Shield icon is displayed in firefox, but it enables it for only one page and one session. I would like to enable it permanently for a whole domain.

Sub-question: is it possible to allow it for certain objects only on all domains? Like for google maps etc. Some sites are running on http://, I change URL to https:// to be safer but then maps are not displayed.

Comment: Does HTTPS Everywhere have any effect? https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found:

- go to `about:config`
- change `security.mixed_content.block_active_content` to `false`.

Unfortunatelly this solution is global for all domains and for all inline objects, which can be extremely insecure in some situations if you are not careful.